# Examples of small, minimalistic natural languages?

Tags: list-of-languages, philosophy-of-language, vocabulary

I was reading about a constructed language called "Toki Pona" that is touted to have only 120 words.

I wanted to know are there any examples of any natural languages notable for their simplicity or relative lack of words?

Comment: Your definition of simplicity only concerns vocabulary pool right?

Comment: That could be one example of simplicity, I was also thinking in terms of grammar too. For example, languages with only a few verb conjugations

Comment: No natural language is that small or simple because human social life isn't that small or simple.

Comment: All languages are the same in terms of grammar. In terms of vocabulary some languages are rich and some are not. That doesn't make them small. If there wasn't 3-4 words for "ache" (as in headache)  in english (unlike Turkish) it only means that there wasn't a need for it.

Comment: All languages are not the same in terms of grammar. Regardless, there are natural languages, called "creoles", that occasionally arise from contact languages, called "pidgins", by creating a generation of children with no other common language. All known creoles have very similar syntactic characteristics (most notably, even when the contributing languages are polysynthetic, like Chinook Jargon, all creole languages are analytic) Creoles, like any other language, don't lack for lexical resources, however; if they need a word, they steal it or make it.

Comment: All languages meet your requirements, when spoken by 2-year-olds.

Comment: @jlawler Even Chinook had plenty of influence from SAE especially by the time it was documented.  My intuition is that the assertion is correct but we must look somewhere else for proof of it.

Comment: For those who have not heard it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogenetic_theory_of_pidgins "This variety was the starting point of all the pidgin and creole languages. This would explain to some extent why Portuguese lexical items can be found in many creoles, but more importantly, it would account for the numerous grammatical similarities shared by such languages."

Comment: Yeah, but very few linguists are impressed by it. Pidgins arise spontaneously, and creolism is not an all-or-nothing proposition. Then there are mixed languages, like Michif, which are a different thing altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one single ritual language that comes quite close with a vocabulary of only some 150 words (having quite broad senses like the Toki Pona ones), namely the aboriginal language Damin

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damin

Comment: I would say that is not a natural language.

Comment: Damin is a natural Australian auxiliary language. Granted, Australian auxiliary languages are pretty weird. See Dixon's mother-in-law language and Hill's upside-down Walbiri, for instance.

Comment: @jlawler can you elaborate on "upside-down walbiri"? A duckduckgo search didn't show anything relevant

Comment: The Hale article is ["A Note on a Walbiri Tradition of Antonymy"](http://lingphil.mit.edu/papers/hale/papers/hale095.pdf), and it's a classic.